# Amazon EC2 - US East vs US West... Does it matter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My question is not so much related to Amazon's specific differences between these two regions, but more about how the distance could affect applications' performance.

I have an application that will only be accessed in by US West users (I know this for sure). However, my EC2 instances are located in US East... Should I worry about that?

Will my applications performance really be that affected?

Retrieving web pages vs streaming media, does this make a big difference?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience it doesn't make a whole lot of difference. But if all your users are in the Western US I would still make my servers run in the us-west-1 or us-west-2 regions. There's probably a slight lower latency, so it also depends on the latency requirements of your customers. For example we have a strict 70ms latency requirement from our customers so we want to have our server located close to our customers.

Furthermore, if you want higher performance you might want to consider upgrading the sizes of your instances (EC2), databases(RDS), etc.

If you want to migrate your app from us-east-1 to any of the us-west regions you can create AMI's for your instances for example and then copy them over using the AWS AMI Copy functionality.